# Webpage error (saying Done, but with errors on page)

Tags: css, html

I'm the administrator for http://fcboro.co.uk and am having problems trying to solve a webpage error. When I load the page up on IE8, I keep getting a error in the bottom left hand corner, saying "Done, but with errors on page."

When I look into it, the message says that the error is on line 22, char 5, but I have no idea where or what this is?

Can someone help me as I have tried to wordpress support forums, but no one has helped.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [IE Developer Toolbar](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2007/01/09/ie-developer-toolbar-beta-3-now-available/) to debug those errors.

[image]
<sub>(source: [winisp.net](http://ieblog.members.winisp.net/images/DTBmenu.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is with the following line in your page:

```
<script src='http://wordpress.com/remote-login.php?action=js&amp;host=fcboro.co.uk&amp;id=3632619&amp;t=1277746475&amp;back=fcboro.co.uk%2F' 
    type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The exact failure occurs a few lines lower, when a Javascript tries to run the method `WPRemoteLogin()`. The error, in Internet Explorer 8, reads that an object is expected, which implies to me that either the `WPRemoteLogin()` method itself does not exist, or a failure is occurring within it.

Neither IE's developer tools nor Firebug in Firefox was able to load the script I pointed out above. My suspicion is that the URL in that script may be off, and that may be what's actually causing the error. I'd start by ensuring I had the correct URL there, and then progress debugging from that point.

If the URL is indeed correct, then I'd start looking for the object which that call is missing. Attempt to load and retrieve that Javascript, and search for `function WPRemoteLogin`. From there, you should be able to trace the code out to the exact point of failure.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am quite limited when it comes to this sort of thing. All I've done recently is edited some of the CSS for the look of the site. I wouldn't know where to find what you're referring to?

Comment: @Gert: Yes, I did. I originally wrote that as just "Firebug in Firefox was unable," before editing it for IE8's dev tools when I validated that it couldn't load either. Corrected. :)

Comment: @sgmboro: If you're truly stumped, you may be in a position where you need to contract out to a WordPress specialist. :( I'm sorry to say that, but without full access to all the scripts in question, there's only so much I can do to debug something like this. :(

Comment: The error only comes up when I'm not logged in, so it's definately something to do with what you were referring to earlier.

Comment: @Gert: No problem; glad someone caught that for me. :)